# Setting default selected option for Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend Framework - Set 'selected' value in select box dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588272/zend-framework-set-selected-value-in-select-box-dropdown-list)

I have a Zend_Form with Zend_Form_Select element. I populate it from array (code inside the *Application_Form_MyForm extends Zend_Form* class):

```
$options = array('first option', 'second option', 'third option');
$this->getElement('mySelect')->addMultiOptions($options);
```

How can I choose which value is gonna be selected automatically, as in `"<option value="second option" selected="selected">second option</option>" ?`
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To populate all form values, you can call $form->populate($dataAsArray);

If you want to set a default value, you can call $select->setValue('valueHere'); If it were a checkbox, instead of pass one sigle value you would pass an array of selected indexes.

See this question: [Zend_Form_Element_MultiSelect element definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488057/zend-form-element-multiselect-element-definition/3488129#3488129)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... populating values of whole form from array ($form->populate) did the trick. I didn't see it working before I dont know why, maybe some bug or the browser aggressively caching.