# set default value in Zend select element

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework

I need to update forms on some site written not by me. It works on WordPress 4.3.1 with plugin WP-ZFF Zend Framework Full 1.11.12-1 installed so WP can use Zend classes.

There is a form what I need to check. The code:

```php
class Form_Registration extends Zend_Form {

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);
        $this->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_URLENCODED);
        $this->setAction("/");
        $this->setAttrib("id", "registration_form");
        $this->setDecorators(array('FormElements', 'tag' => 'form'));

        $myselect = $this->createElement("select", "myselect");
        $myselect->addMultiOption("1","aa");
        $myselect->addMultiOption("2","bb");
        $myselect->addMultiOption("3","cc");
        $myselect->setValue("2");

        echo "value:".$myselect->getValue(); // that prints out "2"

        $this->addElements(array($myselect));
    }
}
```

and using of the code:

```php
$f = new Form_Registration();
$f->isValid($_POST);
print $f->render(new Zend_View());
```

My problem is to set default value for this select element.

I've tried:

- $myselect->setValue("2");
- $this->setDefault('myselect','2');
- $this->populate(array('myselect' => '2'));

Also I've tried to replace `$this->createElement()` with `$this->addElement()` and so to replace it with

```php
$this->addElement('select', 'myselect', array(
    'value' => '2',
    'multiOptions' => array(
            '1' => 'aa',
            '2' => 'bb',
            '3' => 'cc'
        ),
    )
);
```

I've disabled all Javascript to be sure that some script clears form elements.
Nothing works! 
That what I get:

```html
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value="1">aa</option>
<option value="2">bb</option>
<option value="3">cc</option>
</select>
```

What I do wrong and how can I set one of select's option to be 'selected'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488057/zend-form-element-multiselect-element-definition/3488129#3488129

Comment: `setValue()` doesn't work for me as I said. I don't know why

Comment: what does this return? $myselect->getValue()

Comment: @artsylar, see the commented line in my code

Comment: you're calling isValid, so the value is overwritten by the data in $_POST.